# How to get kendo window content from input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have a question about kendo window.
I have a input like this

```
<div id="windowForAssign"></div>
<div>
    <p>Your name</p>
    <input type="text" id="name" >
    <button type="button" id="btnSend">Send</button>
</div>
```

And when I click on button, a window will pop-up. Here, I use Kendo window.

```
$('#btnSend').click(createAndShowPopup);
   var kendoWindowAssign = $("#windowForAssign");
   var title = "Sample title";
   var url = "";

   function createAndShowPopup(){
     kendoWindowAssign.kendoWindow({
       width: "650px",
       modal: true,
       height: '120px',
       iframe: true,
       resizable: false,
       title: title,
       content: null,
       visible: false
     });

     var popup = $("#windowForAssign").data('kendoWindow');
     popup.open();
     popup.center();
   }
```

But I don't know how to get data from input for content.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: There are many ways to achieve that. What is the origin of *data* ?

Comment: Data is from user enteting

Comment: From input text, you mean ? If thats the only content of the modal you can set its value in the `content` parameter. Or there is something Im missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `content` method for this. From Telerik [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/methods/content):

> Gets or sets the content of a Window.

Just pass in the input's value by using `popup.content($("#name").val());`

Dojo example [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/ekaBuREk)

```
<div id="windowForAssign"></div>
<div>
  <p>Your name</p>
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <button type="button" id="btnSend">Send</button>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSend').click(createAndShowPopup);
    var kendoWindowAssign = $("#windowForAssign");
    var title = "Sample title";
    var url = "";

    function createAndShowPopup(){
      kendoWindowAssign.kendoWindow({
        width: "650px",
        modal: true,
        height: '120px',
        iframe: true,
        resizable: false,
        title: title,
        content: null,
        visible: false
      });

      var popup = kendoWindowAssign.data('kendoWindow');
      popup.content($("#name").val());
      popup.open();
      popup.center();
    };
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use the method in this case, since you can set the value of `content` in the intialization parameters.

Answer (score 0):

To get the input value, you can use jQuery as follows:

```
$("#name").val();
```

[Learn more about jQuery's .val() method here](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

This will get you the desired value from the input field that you require to set the content for your window.

Now, set your `content` property that you are specifying in your initialization parameters for your kendo window.
Set the content property to following:

```
content: { template: kendo.template($("#name").val()) }
```

instead of: `content: null`
that you have set.

[Learn more about kendo.Window's content method here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/methods/content)

This should get you the input value for your kendo window on button click event.

Here I am using `kendo.template` method that kendo has to set the content for the kendo window and you can [read more about that here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/template)